# Property of all k-dimesional shapes

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, recreational-mathematics

A close friend showed me an intuitive pattern that given a k-dimensional convex polytope P, if one doubles every sidelength to generate a $P'$ it is possible to fit $2^k$ copies of $P$ within the region of this $P'$ by translation and rotation.

How to prove this though?

I was thinking an inductive argument would make a lot of sense, for example we can try to show it is true for all $k$ dimensional simplices and then somehow make the (getting hand-wavy here) argument that we have a region $2^k$ times larger than the original shape and then from there try to describe a packing scheme.

But even for something as simple as a pentagon what is the packing strategy that results in 4 pentagons fitting into a pentagon of twice the sidelengths?

Comment: It seems unlikely that convex, many-sided polytopes which approximate circles and spheres can be so packed: it would certainly simplify all those papers on sphere packing!

Comment: Your "intuitive pattern" works for squares and equilateral triangles in the plane, but if you try the equilateral hexagon you will see that it fails. (The hexagon is easier to see than the pentagon.)